# What topological object does this planar diagram represent?

Tags: general-topology

A friend showed me a topology question that I could not answer, last time I did any real topology was years ago. The question is

> What object does the identified planar diagram represent:
>
> [image: diagram]
>
> *From the bottom of [this page](https://ima.org.uk/3567/maths-in-a-twist/?fbclid=IwAR0kYHfR0hts9JqVTqyETGoQbrp9U3UtTF69HnhWyTEMcYVB2w3RVXTMxrY)*

I consulted my book, Topology of Surfaces, by Kinsey, but I am really quite rusty on this at the moment. I noticed there is an error in the document where it presents the planar diagram for C (cylinder) where one arrow is up and the other down; this is of course wrong. So I had wondered if the planar diagram with the question mark might be bogus. But the publisher seems to be a genuine mathematician.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Möbius strip. To see this, cut the square along the diagonal (put double arrows along the new edges to not forget that they are identified), and glue the already-drawn arrows. You should now get a classic diagram for Möbius strip.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Moebius strip.  Cut and reassemble as shown.  Notice that the two new identified edges are identified with a half-twist.

[image]